# POCO Request timeout even when keepAlive is set

Tags: httprequest, session-timeout, poco-libraries

I am using a simple Get request to get notification from server. I want the request to persist until response is received from the server (It may be any long 1 to 9 hours). But i am facing the issue of request timeout in 2 mins. I am setting both session and request as "keepalive". But its not helping. I have also tried using setKeepAliveTimeout and given it a large value. But this too didnt changed anything. Below is the code i am using:

```
try{
        //Prepare request
        Poco::URI uri(url);
        const Poco::Net::Context::Ptr context = new Poco::Net::Context(Poco::Net::Context::CLIENT_USE, "", "", "", Poco::Net::Context::VERIFY_NONE, 9, false, "ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH");
        Poco::Net::HTTPSClientSession session(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort(), context);
        session.setKeepAlive(true);

        // prepare path
        std::string path(uri.getPathAndQuery());
        if (path.empty())
        {
            path = "/";
        }

        // send request
        Poco::Net::HTTPRequest req(Poco::Net::HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET, path, Poco::Net::HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
      req.setKeepAlive(true);
        session.sendRequest(req);

        // Get response
        Poco::Net::HTTPResponse res;

        //Get status code
     statusCode = res.getStatus());
        //Get status
        status = res.getReason();

        //Get body
        std::istream &inStream = session.receiveResponse(res);
        std::ostringstream outStringStream;
        outStringStream << inStream.rdbuf();
        response = outStringStream.str();
    }
    catch(Poco::Exception& exception)
    {
       cout<<exception.displayText();
    }
```

Please let me know where i am wrong. Thanks.

I get the status -1 Timeout in around 2 minutes.

Answer (score 9):

This question is somewhat old now, but I have the answer and it took me some time to find it.

It's not the keepAlive setting you want to change as this just keeps the connection open between requests.

Once you've made the request

`session.sendRequest(req);`

(i.e. once the session's underlying socket has been established), Get the session's socket reference and change the receive timeout i.e:

```
StreamSocket &str = session.socket();
// Create a timespan of (e.g.) 600 secs (10 mins)
Timespan ts(600L, 0L);
str.setReceiveTimeout(ts);
```

This worked for me!

Comment: Thanks for posting your findings! This helped me a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Just found this question when searching for the same TimeOut problem when dealing with Google Pub/Sub pull mechanism.

Found out that you can set the timeout of the session:

```
session->setTimeout(Poco::Timespan(10, 0));
```

Must be called before `session->sendRequest(request)`.

Comment: Hi. I know this is an old post. I'm trying to track down a related problem where it seems Poco is not honoring the receive timeout when set after the socket is connected.  Is it only possible to set the receive timeout before it is connected (i.e., before calling sendRequest)? Thanks.